# No Display after Debugging in C++

Tags: c++

So I began my project in C++ and after case 1, decided to Debug and make sure I hadn't made any errors. Only problem is, there is nothing displaying? No errors appear, but the Output is just blank? Under the assumption I totally left something out in the beginning. Please help

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> // for 'fixed' and 'setprecision' 
#include <cmath> // C++ Math Library

// function main begins program execution 
int main()
{
double managWage = 0;
double hourlyWorkers = 0;
double commissionWorkers = 0;
double widgetWorkers = 0;

// a variable to hold their choice 
char selection = 0;
while (selection != 'Q');
// a variable to track the number of transactions 
int transaction = 0;
{

  // Display a menu to the user 
  // You MUST use these integer values (1-5) for the auto evaluator to work 
  std::cout << "(1) Managers" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "(2) Hourly Workers" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "(3) Commission Workers" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "(4) Widget Workers" << std::endl;

  // Ask the user for their choice + Sentinel Value
  std::cout << "Enter pay code <[Q]uit>";
  std::cin >> selection;

  switch (selection)
  {
    case '1':
      //Variables
        int weekSalary = 0;
        managWage = managWage + weekSalary;

        std::cout << "Manager selected." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter weekly salary ";
        std::cin >> weekSalary;
        if (weekSalary < 0)
        {
          std::cout << "Error: Weekly salary can not be less than zero.";
        }
          else
          {
            while (weekSalary >= 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Manager's pay is " << managWage << std::endl;
            } //End while
            break;
          } //End else
        break;

  }
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what IDE / debugger you're using.

Comment: `while (weekSalary >= 0)` part will make infinite loop.

Comment: I can't vouch for any of the videos in the search @ https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B+debugging+beginning&safe=active&tbm=vid but they might be helpful if this is your first time using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem

```
while (selection != 'Q');
```

This results in an infinite while loop. You probably want:

```
while (selection != 'Q')
{
    int transaction = 0;
    ...
```

Here is another one:

```
while (weekSalary >= 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I'm obviously extremely new to this. The IDE is MicrosoftVisualStudio.

Made the initial corrections but debug still gives an output of blank screen?

Comment: Add logging until you understand the issue. First, make the very first line of `main` output something. If you don't get that log, then it's a platform issue. If you do, then at least you know you got that far. Then add logging until you figure out exactly how far your program is getting. (Or learn to use a debugger.)